# Why Mathematica is treating the product of (specified) real variable as complex?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra, assumptions

For the given matrix

```
mat = MatrixForm[{{2*g*a*e, 0, 2*g*a*d, 0, -2*g*a*e, 0, 
 g*(-2*c*d - (b*e)/E^(I*f) - E^(I*f)*b*e), 
 g*((I*b*e)/E^(I*f) - I*E^(I*f)*b*e), 
 g*((-E^((-I)*f))*b*d - E^(I*f)*b*d + 2*c*e)}, 
{0, -2*g*a*e, 0, -2*g*a*e, 0, -2*g*a*d, 
 g*((I*b*e)/E^(I*f) - I*E^(I*f)*b*e), 
 g*(-2*c*d + (b*e)/E^(I*f) + E^(I*f)*b*e), 
 g*((I*b*d)/E^(I*f) - I*E^(I*f)*b*d)}, 
{2*g*a*c, 0, g*((a*b)/E^(I*f) + E^(I*f)*a*b), 0, -2*g*a*c, 
 g*((I*a*b)/E^(I*f) - I*E^(I*f)*a*b), 
 g*((-E^((-I)*f))*b*c - E^(I*f)*b*c + 2*d*e), 
 g*((I*b*c)/E^(I*f) - I*E^(I*f)*b*c), g*(a^2 - b^2 + c^2 + d^2 - e^2)}}]
```

simplifying the singular values treats the products like `a*b`, `b*c` etc as complex even when they are defined as real. How to sort this issue?

```
 T1[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_] = Simplify[SingularValueList[mat][[1]][[1]], 
   Assumptions -> Element[a, Reals] && Element[b, Reals] && 
     Element[c, Reals] && Element[d, Reals] && Element[e, Reals] && 
     Element[a*b, Reals] && Element[a*c, Reals] && Element[a*d, Reals] && 
     Element[a*e, Reals] && Element[b*c, Reals] && Element[b*d, Reals] && 
     Element[b*e, Reals] && Element[c*d, Reals] && Element[c*e, Reals] && 
     Element[d*e, Reals] && 0 < f < Pi && 0 < g < 1]
```

Which gives for `T1[a, b, c, d, 0, \[Pi]/2, g]` the following:

```
 Root[-16*a^8*d^4*g^6 + 16*a^4*b^4*d^4*g^6 - 192*a^6*c^2*d^4*g^6 + 
    32*a^2*b^4*c^2*d^4*g^6 - 352*a^4*c^4*d^4*g^6 + 16*b^4*c^4*d^4*g^6 - 
    192*a^2*c^6*d^4*g^6 - 16*c^8*d^4*g^6 - 32*a^6*d^6*g^6 - 
    96*a^4*c^2*d^6*g^6 - 96*a^2*c^4*d^6*g^6 - 32*c^6*d^6*g^6 - 
    16*a^4*d^8*g^6 - 32*a^2*c^2*d^8*g^6 - 16*c^4*d^8*g^6 - 
    128*a^4*b*c^2*d^3*g^6*Conjugate[b*d] - 128*a^2*b*c^4*d^3*g^6*
     Conjugate[b*d] - 32*a^5*d^3*g^6*Conjugate[a*b]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    32*a^3*b^2*d^3*g^6*Conjugate[a*b]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    64*a^3*c^2*d^3*g^6*Conjugate[a*b]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    32*a*b^2*c^2*d^3*g^6*Conjugate[a*b]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    32*a*c^4*d^3*g^6*Conjugate[a*b]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    32*a^3*d^5*g^6*Conjugate[a*b]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    32*a*c^2*d^5*g^6*Conjugate[a*b]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    32*a^4*c*d^3*g^6*Conjugate[b*c]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    32*a^2*b^2*c*d^3*g^6*Conjugate[b*c]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    64*a^2*c^3*d^3*g^6*Conjugate[b*c]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    32*b^2*c^3*d^3*g^6*Conjugate[b*c]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    32*c^5*d^3*g^6*Conjugate[b*c]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    32*a^2*c*d^5*g^6*Conjugate[b*c]*Conjugate[b*d] - 
    32*c^3*d^5*g^6*Conjugate[b*c]*Conjugate[b*d] + 
    (8*a^6*d^2*g^4 - 8*a^4*b^2*d^2*g^4 + 88*a^4*c^2*d^2*g^4 - 
      16*a^2*b^2*c^2*d^2*g^4 + 88*a^2*c^4*d^2*g^4 - 8*b^2*c^4*d^2*g^4 + 
      8*c^6*d^2*g^4 + 32*a^4*d^4*g^4 - 8*a^2*b^2*d^4*g^4 + 
      64*a^2*c^2*d^4*g^4 - 8*b^2*c^2*d^4*g^4 + 32*c^4*d^4*g^4 + 
      8*a^2*d^6*g^4 + 8*c^2*d^6*g^4 + 16*a^3*b*d^2*g^4*Conjugate[a*b] + 
      16*a*b*c^2*d^2*g^4*Conjugate[a*b] + 16*a^2*b*c*d^2*g^4*
       Conjugate[b*c] + 16*b*c^3*d^2*g^4*Conjugate[b*c] + 
      32*a^2*b*c^2*d*g^4*Conjugate[b*d] + 16*a^2*b*d^3*g^4*Conjugate[b*d] + 
      16*b*c^2*d^3*g^4*Conjugate[b*d] + 8*a^3*d*g^4*Conjugate[a*b]*
       Conjugate[b*d] + 8*a*b^2*d*g^4*Conjugate[a*b]*Conjugate[b*d] + 
      8*a*c^2*d*g^4*Conjugate[a*b]*Conjugate[b*d] + 
      8*a*d^3*g^4*Conjugate[a*b]*Conjugate[b*d] + 
      8*a^2*c*d*g^4*Conjugate[b*c]*Conjugate[b*d] + 
      8*b^2*c*d*g^4*Conjugate[b*c]*Conjugate[b*d] + 
      8*c^3*d*g^4*Conjugate[b*c]*Conjugate[b*d] + 
      8*c*d^3*g^4*Conjugate[b*c]*Conjugate[b*d])*#1 + 
    ((-a^4)*g^2 + 2*a^2*b^2*g^2 - b^4*g^2 - 10*a^2*c^2*g^2 + 
      2*b^2*c^2*g^2 - c^4*g^2 - 10*a^2*d^2*g^2 + 2*b^2*d^2*g^2 - 
      10*c^2*d^2*g^2 - d^4*g^2 - 4*a*b*g^2*Conjugate[a*b] - 
      4*b*c*g^2*Conjugate[b*c] - 4*b*d*g^2*Conjugate[b*d])*#1^2 + #1^3 & , 
  1]
```

Answer (score 10):

You are probably not using Mathematica correctly. First, you shouldn't put `MatrixForm` into `SingularValueList`. Second, the way you defined your matrix and function `T1` does not work for properly applying the parameters. Lastly, use `ComplexExpand` to simplify the expression, assuming all variables are real, or `Simplify`/`Refine`.

```
Clear[T1, mat];

mat[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, 
  g_] := {{2*g*a*e, 0, 2*g*a*d, 0, -2*g*a*e, 0, 
   g*(-2*c*d - (b*e)/E^(I*f) - E^(I*f)*b*e), 
   g*((I*b*e)/E^(I*f) - I*E^(I*f)*b*e), 
   g*((-E^((-I)*f))*b*d - E^(I*f)*b*d + 2*c*e)}, {0, -2*g*a*e, 
   0, -2*g*a*e, 0, -2*g*a*d, g*((I*b*e)/E^(I*f) - I*E^(I*f)*b*e), 
   g*(-2*c*d + (b*e)/E^(I*f) + E^(I*f)*b*e), 
   g*((I*b*d)/E^(I*f) - I*E^(I*f)*b*d)}, {2*g*a*c, 0, 
   g*((a*b)/E^(I*f) + E^(I*f)*a*b), 0, -2*g*a*c, 
   g*((I*a*b)/E^(I*f) - I*E^(I*f)*a*b), 
   g*((-E^((-I)*f))*b*c - E^(I*f)*b*c + 2*d*e), 
   g*((I*b*c)/E^(I*f) - I*E^(I*f)*b*c), 
   g*(a^2 - b^2 + c^2 + d^2 - e^2)}};

T1[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_] := 
 First@SingularValueList[mat[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]]

T1[a, b, c, d, 0, \[Pi]/2, g]
(* Sqrt[4 a d g Conjugate[a d g] + 4 c d g Conjugate[c d g]] *)

Refine[%, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g} \[Element] Reals]
(* Sqrt[4 a^2 d^2 g^2 + 4 c^2 d^2 g^2] *)

Simplify[%, Assumptions -> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g} \[Element] Reals]
(* 2 Sqrt[a^2 + c^2] Abs[d] Abs[g] *)
```